# Deploy to multiple AWS lambda

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda

I have an application that should process multiple independent inputs.
The app is written in .net core 3.1 and I'm using AWS toolkit to deploy it from VS code into lambda function (with "lambda deploy-function").

How can I deploy the same code onto multiple lambdas and them with different arguments?

Even better, is it possible to create many lambdas from VS Code command & deploy the function onto them & invoke each instances with specific arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ServerLess](https://www.serverless.com/) also seems to be a good tool suggested by @Asif.
But I have started to use the [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/). For me it seems to be a more handy.

Answer (score 0):

Go with [Serverless](https://www.serverless.com) framework to deploy multiple lambda function with different arguments. Define the function in one place and reference it in multiple lambda function configuration. You need to add few lines (3-5) for each new function copy in serverless.yml file.

It is also a quite handy tool for deploying faster and large applications.